# Dumping from NiFi to Redshift using PutDataBaseRecord Processor is really slow

Tags: performance, amazon-redshift, etl, apache-nifi

I am new to both Redshift and Apache NiFi. I am trying to dump CSV record (~3000 rows per record) every 15 minutes into a Redshift table using JDBC connection. The PutDatabaseRecord Processor is taking approx 18 min for dumping a single record. How could I speed this process up and avoid the Flowfile queue and increasing thread count in my NiFi cluster.

Comment: Do you Insert one by one or batch in the Redshift?

Comment: @MuhammadReza I insert a single CSV of ~3000 records as a single batch